# Get strings inside four brackets (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

How i can write something like this:

```
var s = "[hello world](one two)";
var x = s.replace(REGEX, '<p>$1</p><b>$2</b>');
```

output:

```
<p>hello world</p><b>one two</b>
```

Comment: `/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/`???

Comment: Its working! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex with [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```js
var s = "[hello world](one two)";
var x = s.replace(/\[([^\]]*)]\(([^)]*)\)/, '<p>$1</p><b>$2</b>');

console.log(x);
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/szimYJ/1)

Comment: this is much safer than my answer. If you use inverted char classes, there is IMHO no reason to not allow an empty string. I would replace the + by a *.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log( "[hello world](one two)".replace(/\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)/, '<p>$1</p><b>$2</b>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use capture groups with regex.exec(string) and this (([.*])|((.*)))+ (or enything that resembles to this) and build theoputut string